# WPF c# change sender property in event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, properties, sender

Is it possible to change sender's property in event?

I have my own control in wpf with 10 Image controls.
I set on all of them mouse enter and mouse leave events.
All those events do the same(change size and Z index) but for specific Image.

With changing sender's property in event I will have only 2 event's methods, not 20.
When I tried to change sender's property I saw it was readonly.

Is it possible to do ?

Comment: What do you  mean by "change sender's property?" Which property is readonly? When you handle an event you are passed an argument typically called `sender`, and that is usually passed as an `object` which is certainly editable - but individual properties on that object would depend what the object is! I think you need to be a little clearer in your question (maybe post some code?). My best guess is that what you really want to do is attach the same 1 event handling method to the events on your 10 different controls - which is totally possible.

Comment: Raise new event - created by you. BTW, show your code.

Comment: Delete all your code immediately and learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. You should not create your own control to host items (regardless of what these items are). That's what the [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) is for.

Answer (score 0):

Point all your controls at the same handlers. You can do this at design time or through code.

In the handler cast sender to the type of control.

Now when you change it's properties, you are changing the properties of the control that raised the event

PS don't forget to check to see if the cast is valid, before you try to access it's members.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you  can do it in xaml

```
/ <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void image1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //put your code here and all your images will points here 
        }

        private void image1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
             //put your code here and all your images will points here 
        }
    }
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,116,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="image1_MouseLeave" />
        <Image Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,116,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="image1_MouseLeave" />
        <Image Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,116,0,0" Name="image3" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="image1_MouseLeave" />
        <Image Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,116,0,0" Name="image4" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="image1_MouseLeave" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

//and here in code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        image1.MouseEnter += image1_MouseEnter;
        image2.MouseEnter += image1_MouseEnter;
        image3.MouseEnter += image1_MouseEnter;
        image4.MouseEnter += image1_MouseEnter;


        image1.MouseEnter += image1_MouseLeave;
        image2.MouseEnter += image1_MouseLeave;
        image3.MouseEnter += image1_MouseLeave;
        image4.MouseEnter += image1_MouseLeave;

    }

    private void image1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void image1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```